# Проблема в ie7 boxsizing.htc: текст справа от картинки столбиком

Tags: css3, html, internet-explorer, css

Появилась проблема в ie7 благодаря boxsizing.htc. Есть картинка, которая обрамлена в `div`, этот `div` имеет `float:left`; после этого дива идет параграф `<p>Ткст....</p>` с текстом, текст должен обрамлять картинку, но почему-то текст становится справа от картинки столбиком. Причина - это boxsizing.htc, если убрать его, то всё нормально. Хотелось бы понять, почему так происходит.

```
<style>
html * {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
  *behavior: url(css/htc-libs/boxsizing.htc);

}
.md_img {float:left;}

.md_text p {line-height:20px;}
</style>

<div class="md_text">

   <div class="md_img">
      <img src="i/src/img/img-1.png" alt="">
   </div>

<p>Текст....</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Видел решиние этой ситуации здесь [habr](http://habrahabr.ru/post/50175/)